# jQuery, closing menu

Tags: jquery, menu, popup

I need help with a menu I'm adding on a jQuery chat system called cometchat.
I've been trying to add a Facebook like applications menu and I got it to work with opening and closing and it closes clicking everywhere in the body and the bar but the place it should open and close.

Here is the piece of code:

```
a("#cometchat_base").append(
  '<div id="cometchat_application" class="cometchat_application menu">
    <strong>Menu</a></strong>
  </div>');

a("#cometchat_base").append(
  '<div class="menu-content" style="
      display:none;
      position:absolute;
      bottom: 30px;
      left: 20px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      background-color:White;
      padding: 5px;">
    <div>
      <a href="#">Menu option 1</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Menu option 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>');

a(".cometchat_application,.menu").click(function(){
  a(".menu-content").hide();
  a(this).next().show();
  return false;}
);

a("#page-bg,#cometchat_base,.menu-content a").click(function(){
  a(".menu-content").hide();}
);

a(".boo,.menu-content a").click(function(){alert(a(this));});
```

I tried to change `a("#page-bg,#cometchat_base,.menu-content a")` and add the button div class but then it wont open anymore. And the `alert(a(this);` I couldn't change so it just opens the link without any alerts.

Answer (score 0):

In your first line of code, you don't close the `<div>` you are appending... that being said it might help if you included a little more code and some HTML to base this on.

Also, it would be easier to read and cleaner if you put all the CSS into the stylesheet and formatted the code on more than one line for us :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok... so with a lot of trials and errors me learning js yay!!!!
So that mess of codes i tried before ended up like this

//Menu button on bottom bar
`(<div/>)`
`.attr("id","cometchat_menu")`
`.addClass("cometchat_menu")`
`.html("<strong>Menu</strong>")`
`.appendTo("#cometchat_base");`

//Popup menu when button clicked
`a("<div/>")`
`.addClass("menu-content")`
`.css("display","none")`
`.css("position","absolute")`
`.css("bottom","24px")`
`.css("border","0px")`
`.css("padding","0px")`
`.css("width","150px")`
`.html('...my menu body...')`
`.appendTo("#cometchat_base");`

//Command to show and hide the popup
`a(".cometchat_menu")
.click(function(){
if(a(this).hasClass("cometchat_menuopen")){a(this).removeClass("cometchat_menuopen");a(".menu-content").hide();}else{a(this).addClass("cometchat_menuopen");a("#menu-content").hide();a(this).next().show();return false;}});`

And now my button works :) hope it can help other people too.

Comment: Good to see you got your answer! I just wanted to add that you can add multiple attributes or css parameters like this: a("<div/>").css( { "display":"none","position":"absolute","bottom":"24px", etc  } )

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Drop Down Menu

The best thing in jquery is we can create custom function and bind/unbind them to live events.

The **on click** action on the needs to be captured to close the open meny either clicked on the same link or anywhere on body should close the menu

In my case i wanted to close a drop down menu if its clicked on primary link or outside the link i.e. anywhere on the html/body

http://jsfiddle.net/austinnoronha/k2Lwj/

```
var toggleClick = function(){

    var divObj = $(this).next();
    var nstyle = divObj.css("display");

    if(nstyle == "none"){
        divObj.slideDown(false,function(){
            $("html").bind("click",function(){
                divObj.slideUp();
                $("html").unbind("click");
            });
        });
    }
};

$(".clickme").click(toggleClick);
```